# Firebase Storage Java client with JWT from webapp

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Java client application that writes records to Firestore and attempts to upload files to Firebase Storage.

When the application starts I'm using Angular to authenticate the user with Firestore. From within the Angular app, I can write to the database and upload files just fine so my permissions here are correct.

However, I want to take that same JWT and reuse it in the Java client. I can successfully use that JWT to write to Firestore with something like:

```
// Using com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:3.0.2
final AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(configService.getToken(), null);

final FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions =
        FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
                .setProjectId("project-id")
                .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(GoogleCredentials.create(accessToken)))
                .build();
```

This works no problem.

Now attempting to do a similar thing

```
// Using com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:2.1.7
final AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(configService.getToken(), null);

final StorageOptions storageOptions = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
        .setProjectId("project-id")
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.create(accessToken))
        .build();
```

Trying to upload a file using:

```
public void upload(File zipFile, FileObject fileObject)
{
    final Storage storage = firebaseService.getStorage();

    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("gs://project-url/uploads/userId/items/" + fileObject.getId(), zipFile.getName());

    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
    storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(zipFile.getAbsolutePath())));
}
```

I get back

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
```

So it looks like my JWT is being rejected, but only for the calls to `Storage`

Is there some other library or package that will allow me to do this, or some other method?

I'd really like to avoid having to build and deploy a middleware server to first upload to before sending it off to `Storage`.

Note: I can't use Firebase Admin SDK as this is distributed to clients.

Comment: Are you using service account credentials to Authenticate the firebase storage? Can you please check if [this link helps you](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)?

Comment: No, I'm not, that would require me to distribute the service credentials with the application would it not? Surely not something you'd want to be doing.

Comment: Do you have both storage and firestore under the same project?  If not can you please provide the same service account for both projects for authentication? Also check the storage permissions of your current account from IAM if you have enough permissions to write or read the files to the current bucket.